# What a "Test validations: Expired" means in azure devop?

Tags: azure, testing, azure-devops, devops

We have a Test pipeline in azure devop, and we have set it to execute on pull requests.

But in one of the PR, we see this:

[image]

The tests have suceeded, have been executed yesterday, but I don't understand what means this Expired here. Do you have an explanation? How to finish this PR if this was an mandatory check?

Comment: I'd check PR policies in the repository settings. My guess is that it expires once code changes or there is a time limit after which validation has to be repeated.

Comment: @szachmat You're right, there is a "If the target(develop) branch has updates, there is a grace period of 12h during which the tests results are still valid. So what would be the expected way to solve this? Merge develop back to the feature branch even if there is no conflicts?

Comment: I have never dealt with such scenario myself, but I strongly believe you should be able to repeat the check somewhere in the UI (perhaps under these 3 dots button on the right hand side?). A dirty workaround would be to create dummy commit, e.g. with new line. This should trigger test validation.

Comment: Well, I didn't manage to create a new validation, but merging develop to the branch of the source of the pull request triggers a new tests. If you create an answers with our discussion, I will accept it!

Comment: Thanks, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely there is a pull request policy to expire test results after specific time period.
When it comes to repeating the test validation, new commit should do the work.